# SQL COUNT return multiple rows

Tags: sql

I have those two Tables:

tblCommentReactions

| id | Liked | CommentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 |

1 is Like and 0 is dislike.

tblComments:

| id | userID | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | message 1 |
| 2 | 1 | message 2 |
| 3 | 2 | message 1 |

I tried to select all comments and Count the dislikes and likes and give the result in the same Row.

```
SELECT c.ID as CommentID, c.message,
COUNT(case when Liked = 1 AND r.CommentID = c.ID then 1 else null end) as likes, 
COUNT(case when Liked = 0 AND r.CommentID = c.ID then 1 else null end) as dislikes
FROM tblcomments as c LEFT JOIN tblcommentreactions as r ON c.ID = r.CommentID
WHERE c.userID = 1;
```

Expected Output should be:

| CommentID | message | likes | dislikes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | message 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | message 2 | 0 | 1 |

On my Return it counts everything and only returns the first message. Could you tell me what i need to change in my request, to get my expected output?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? I'm guessing MySQL, because most RDBMS wouldn't allow this without `GROUP BY c.ID, c.message` (or sometimes `GROUP BY c.ID`).

Comment: In your case statement "AND r.CommentID = c.ID" redundant because it's taken care of by the LEFT JOIN.
You could also use ELSE 0 because it's in a COUNT function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your query:

- you have no `GROUP BY` clause in presence of non-aggregated fields inside the `SELECT` clause, which will bring you have an error fired by the DBMS in the best case scenario, no error but random/subtle semantic errors in the worst one.
- you are attempting to filter your rows (the `WHERE` condition) before the aggregation is applied.

In order to solve:

- the first problem, you need to add the `GROUP BY` clause with the two missing selected fields, namely "*c.ID*" and "*c.message*"
- the second problem, you need to transform your current `WHERE` clause into an `HAVING` one (as long as this one applies after the aggregation has been carried out) and add the checked field, namely "*c.userID*", inside the `GROUP BY` clause, as long as it is a field that was selected along with the fields in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT c.ID as CommentID, 
       c.message,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Liked = 1 THEN 1 END) AS likes, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Liked = 0 THEN 1 END) AS dislikes
FROM      tblComments         AS c 
LEFT JOIN tblCommentReactions AS r 
       ON c.ID = r.CommentID
GROUP BY c.ID,
         c.message,
         c.userID
HAVING c.userID = 1
```

Minor fixes on the `CASE` construct that doesn't require "*AND r.CommentID = c.ID*" as already pointed in the comments section, but also the non-required "*ELSE NULL*" condition, that is considered by PostgreSQL as default for this construct.

Here's a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mrgMxichnpqSt8iR6noy4q/1) in MySQL, though this should work in the most common DBMS' more or less.

Answer (score 0):

Try using group by clause e.g

```
select cr.CommentID ,c.message,
    COUNT(case when Liked = 1 AND cr.CommentID = c.ID then 1 else null end) as likes ,
    COUNT(case when Liked = 0 AND cr.CommentID = c.ID then 1 else null end) as dislikes
    
    from [tblCommentReactions] cr inner join tblComments c on cr.CommentID = c.id
    
    group by cr.CommentID , c.message
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.Id,  COUNT(cr1.Liked), COUNT(cr2.Liked)
FROM Comments c
LEFT JOIN CommentReactions cr1 ON cr1.CommentId = c.Id AND cr1.Liked = 0
LEFT JOIN CommentReactions cr2 ON cr2.CommentId = c.Id AND cr2.Liked = 1
GROUP BY c.Id
```